# Volley 405 error : com.android.volley.ClientError

Tags: android, android-volley

this is my code and it works well for all api except one and throws 405 error

```
public void postDataVolley(final String requestType, String url, final HashMap params){
        try{
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (mResultCallBack!=null){
                        mResultCallBack.notifySuccess(requestType,response);
                    }
                    Log.i("Volley Response",response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallBack!=null){
                        mResultCallBack.notifyError(requestType,error);
                    }
                    Log.i("Error Response", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> paramsPass=params;
                    return paramsPass;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

i called the above method using this code from other class as given below

```
        volleyService=new VolleyService(this,mContext);
        volleyService.postDataVolley("POST", url, params);
```

when i search for 405 error everyone suggest me to change the method POST to GET but the api requires POST method..

What is 405 error..?

How can i resolve it

Comment: What are you trying to send to the server? Can you not use `Request.Method.Get`?

Comment: i'm trying to send user_id and access_token to the server to get Profile details

Answer (score -1):

The `405 Method Not Allowed` is an `HTTP` response status code indicating that the specified request `HTTP` method was received and recognized by the server, but the server has rejected that particular method for the requested resource. This message is distinctly different from the `404 Not Found code`.

`404 Not Found error` indicates that the requested resource could not be found, and is often the result of an incorrect URL, or trying to access a resource for which the client has inadequate permissions. Conversely, a `405` code response confirms that the requested resource is valid and exists, but the client has used an unacceptable `HTTP` method during the request.

For More [Click Here](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: You've explained what a HTTP 405 means. You haven't helped the OP with their problem.

Comment: I mentioned a link there you can find out what's the problem on your server-side. This is a backend issue so try to communicate with your backend team.